# Gradle not to run a task in offline mode

Tags: gradle, offline-mode

I couldn't find the answer to this question anywhere else.
How can I set a task to "not run" if running gradle in offline mode?
Is there anyway I can check in the task if `--offline` is passed to grade?

Basically I have some tasks that I want to be able to turn off if I don't have access to internet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Try using startparameter: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html:

```
if(project.getGradle().startParameter.isOffline()) {
  // do something
}
```